# Firebase storage image by username

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I have saved my users profile images in Firebase Storage by username.

How do I retrieve the image for a user?

I keep getting the same error message:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code:

```
let filePath = "\("profileImage/\(self.userNameText.text!)")"
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).data(withMaxSize: INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in
            let profileImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.profileImage.image = profileImage
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

`unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` means that you're trying to use a value that's returning nil so it doesn't exist.

On what exact line are you getting this error?

Comment: I´m getting the error in the line

let profileImage = UIImage(data:data)

Comment: Yes, so this error means that you're force unwrapping the parameter 'data' but data is empty which causes a crash. So your problem is somewhere in this line:

`let filePath = "\("profileImage/\(self.userNameText.text!)")"
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).data(withMaxSize: INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in`